# Read CSV with comma as linebreak

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a file saved as .csv

```
"400":0.1,"401":0.2,"402":0.3
```

Ultimately I want to save the data in a proper format in a csv file for further processing. The problem is that there are no line breaks in the file.

```
pathname = r"C:\pathtofile\file.csv"    

with open(pathname, newline='') as file:
    reader = file.read().replace(',', '\n')
    print(reader)
    with open(r"C:\pathtofile\filenew.csv", 'w') as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
        csv_writer.writerow(reader)
```

The print reader output looks exactly how I want (or at least it's a format I can further process).

```
"400":0.1
"401":0.2
"402":0.3
```

And now I want to save that to a new csv file. However the output looks like

```
"""",4,0,0,"""",:,0,.,1,"
","""",4,0,1,"""",:,0,.,2,"
","""",4,0,2,"""",:,0,.,3
```

I'm sure it would be intelligent to convert the format to

```
400,0.1
401,0.2
402,0.3
```

at this stage instead of doing later with another script.

The main problem is that my current code

```
with open(pathname, newline='') as file:
    reader = file.read().replace(',', '\n')
    reader = csv.reader(reader,delimiter=':')
    x = []
    y = []
    print(reader)
    for row in reader:
        x.append( float(row[0]) )
        y.append( float(row[1]) )           

print(x)
print(y)
```

works fine for the type of csv files I currently have, but doesn't work for these mentioned above:

```
y.append( float(row[1]) )
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I'm trying to find a way to work with them too. I think I'm missing something obvious as I imagine that it can't be too hard to properly define the linebreak character and delimiter of a file.

```
with open(pathname, newline=',') as file:
```

yields

```
ValueError: illegal newline value: ,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way with `csv` module, without replacing and casting to `float`:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f, open('filenew.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(out, quotechar=None)
    for r in reader:
        for i in r:
            writer.writerow(i.split(':'))
```

The resulting `filenew.csv` contents (according to your "***intelligent***" condition):

```
400,0.1
401,0.2
402,0.3
```

---

***Nuances***:

- `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` objects treat comma `,` as default delimiter (no need to `file.read().replace(',', '\n')`)
- `quotechar=None` is specified for `csv.writer` object to eliminate double quotes around the values being saved

Comment: Works like a charme! I know that , is the default delimiter, that's why I wanted to have my "intelligent" format in the end. How does splitting at : result in having a new line for each ,?

Comment: @idkfa, each `"400":0.1` sequence is considered as a field. Splitting a sequence by `:` will give a list of values considered as separate row for the output file

Comment: So because my data is in the format field1,field2,field3 splitting each field will result in a new line? So when I split field1 in part1_field1 and part2_field1 it will automatically be converted to part1_field1,part2_field1\n? That's neat.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the values to form a list to represent a row. Presently the code is splitting the string into individual characters to represent the row.

```
pathname = r"C:\pathtofile\file.csv"    

with open(pathname) as old_file:
    with open(r"C:\pathtofile\filenew.csv", 'w') as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',')
        text_rows = old_file.read().split(",")
        for row in text_rows:
            items = row.split(":")
            csv_writer.writerow([int(items[0]), items[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation, for [`write_row`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects), it says:

> Write the row parameter to the writer’s file
>   object, formatted according to the current dialect.

But, you are writing  an entire string in your code

```
csv_writer.writerow(reader)
```

because `reader` is a string at this point. 
Now, the format you want to use in your CSV file is not clearly mentioned in the question. But as you said, if you can do some preprocessing to create a list of lists and pass each sublist to `writerow()`, you should be able to produce the required file format.

Comment: This answer definitly helped me understanding my mistake in my usage of writerow, but the crucial part on how to split my file correctly is missing in comparison to the other answers. I'd be fine with either format, but I think my "intelligent" format should be the most commonly used format for csv files.